# How to configure spans for constructor in opentelemetry with autoconfigure

Tags: java, open-telemetry

I'm using Opentelemetry with javaagent and autoconfiguration. I can add spans with OTEL_INSTRUMENTATION_METHODS_INCLUDE property. I'm using next system property to create spans for `deploy` and `process` methods:

```
Dotel.instrumentation.methods.include=org.management.MyManagerImpl[process,deploy]
```

But I need add span for constructor also to trace class instance creation. How I can configure it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by `otel.instrumentation.methods.include` today.

It could probably be supported in that feature by checking for `<init>` and using `isConstructor()` instead of `named()` in [MethodInstrumentation.java](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/c74616292ac08fc81db0af1b0045bdf3c9d50392/instrumentation/methods/javaagent/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/javaagent/instrumentation/methods/MethodInstrumentation.java#L50).

Alternatively, you could write an [extension](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/examples/extension#extensions), which would give you this control.